# How do I reach an anchor href if I have trapped the onclick event to zoom and pan in an SVG document?

Tags: javascript, svg, dom-events

I have an SVG document where I have used javascript to implement the zoom and pan functionality [adapted from Andrea Leofreddi's SVGPan library]. The SVG itself has an anchor element which should launch a separate url. My problem is that since the onclick event has been trapped for zoom and pan the href on the anchor is not reached. How can I insulate the anchor from the onclick trap?

In the code below, when I click on the text "Kitchen Sink" I would like to launch the url attached to it rather than entering the zoom and pan mode:

Code fragments:

SVGLib.js:

```
...
setupHandlers(root);

function setupHandlers(root){
    setAttributes(root, {
        "onclick" : "handleClick(evt)"
    });
        root.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', handleMouseWheel, false); 
}


function handleClick(evt) {

    if(evt.preventDefault)
        evt.preventDefault();
    evt.returnValue = false;

    var svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;
    var g = getRoot(svgDoc);

        // Get the click location
        // If key button clicked with shift key down, reset
        if (evt.shiftKey == 1) {
                setCTM(g, root.createSVGMatrix());
                shiftX = initShiftX;
                shiftY = initShiftY;
        }
        else {
                var ctm = g.getCTM();
                var ctmInv = ctm.inverse();
                var newctm = g.getCTM();
                // showMatrix('before: ', newctm);
                shiftX = shiftX - (evt.clientX - initShiftX);
                shiftY = shiftY - (evt.clientY - initShiftY);
                newctm.e = shiftX * vbCTMInv.a;
                newctm.f = shiftY * vbCTMInv.d;
                // bring in the scale factors from the vbCTMInv -- because scaling will apply automatically via the vb transform
                newctm.a = newctm.a*vbCTMInv.a;
                newctm.d = newctm.d*vbCTMInv.d;
                // showMatrix('after: ', newctm);
                setCTM(g, newctm);
        }
}
```

doc.html:

```
<html>
...
<svg>
...
        <g id="g33" style="fill: none; stroke: green">
            <a xlink:href="/cgi-bin/qbui/drive.pl?sqlHandle=693F1DB6-6C7F-11E1-8475-31DDD99CA768">
                <text id="t2769800058" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px" x="600" y="1300">Kitchen Sink</text>
            </a>
        </g>
...
</svg>
</html>
```

Update:

I have figured out a work-around which I can use to detect the event target and take appropriate action. The id is the SVG text element's id if "Kitchen Sink" is clicked. Of course this requires some change in the code but it is do-able.

In handleClick():

```
if (evt.target.id == ...)  {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the href value of evt.target is has a value and if it has follow it

```
function handleClick(evt) {
  if(evt.target.href){
    window.location = evt.target.href;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Based on your suggestion, I have the following working code: ` 
                if (evt.target.parentNode.getAttribute("xlink:href")) {
                        window.open(evt.target.parentNode.getAttribute("xlink:href"));
                }`